# Need files in all subfolders except one

Tags: ruby, regex

I wrote the below condition to get all `*.js` files from a folder and its subfolder. I wrote the below command to get the list:

```
c:/svn/myfolder/**/*.js
```

`"myfolder"` has 4 sub folders `a, b, c, d` in it and i want to get list of `.js` files only from three of the subfolders and skip checking the subfolder `'c'`.

Currently it returns all `.js` files as i put `myfolder/**/*.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby's glob syntax borrows from regex. You can specify a range of characters using brackets.

```
Dir['c:/svn/myfolder/[abd]/*.js']
```

This will include a, b, and d but not c. You can also negate:

```
Dir['c:/svn/myfolder/[^c]/*.js']
```

This will include all but c

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob for more info on Ruby globs.

Comment: Hi, sorry, that subfolders was just an example, my subfolders are having more than character, they are 'fodler 1', 'folder 2' etc..

Comment: Then you might use pattern alternation `{foo,bar}` or one of the other glob features from the link I included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dir glob to get all the files and directories as a list.  To accomplish this with regex do:

```
Dir.glob(File.join(['c:/svn/myfolder', '*[^excluded_folder]', '**', '*.js']))
```

The `*[^excluded_folder]` includes everything but **excluded_folder**.

Keeping the `**` as part of your path will grab files from the current directory path it's placed at as well as all subdirectories.